# Using cloudwatch api get_metric_data to get sagemaker endpoints invocation metrics

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to use aws cloudwatch api get_metric_data to get sagemaker endpoint invocation metrics in python, and it returns me empty timestamps and Values, but there are some invocations between the time I specified, so there is something going wrong. Below is the code I write in python.

```
cloudwatch.get_metric_data(
MetricDataQueries=[
    {
        'Id': 'm1',
        'MetricStat': {
            'Metric': {
                'Namespace': 'AWS/SageMaker',
                'MetricName': 'Invocations',
                'Dimensions': [
                    {
                        'Name': 'EndpointName',
                        'Value': 'users-hcl-2',
                    },
                    {
                        'Name': 'VariantName',
                        'Value': 'AllTraffic',
                    },
                ]
            },
            'Period': 3600,
            'Stat': 'Sum',
            'Unit': 'None'
        },
        'ReturnData': True,
    },
],
StartTime=datetime(2019, 2, 1),
EndTime=datetime(2019,2,13),
)
```

And it returns below:

```
    {'MetricDataResults': [{'Id': 'm1',
   'Label': 'Invocations',
   'Timestamps': [],
   'Values': [],
   'StatusCode': 'Complete'}],
 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '8dd847eb-3b43-11e9-b50f-5f6fedb3e07d',
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '8dd847eb-3b43-11e9-b50f-5f6fedb3e07d',
   'content-type': 'text/xml',
   'content-length': '494',
   'date': 'Thu, 28 Feb 2019 10:28:13 GMT'},
  'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

As I said, the timestamp and values shouldn't be empty, can you help me to sort out where I did wrong, I found some useful links below:

cloudwatch concepts: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html

invocation metrics info:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatch.html

cloudwatch get_metric_data api:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/[cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_data](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_data)

For what I have already tried, changing "Period" entity to different values, but it does no help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you got all of the dimensions correctly, two things to do first would be:

1. Try changing the unit to `Count` or remove the unit completely.
2. Check that you're calling the correct region. Set it explicitly in your client to the target region, like this for example: `cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='TARGET-REGION')`

Here are general instructions on how to debug empty data responses: [How to retrieve AWS Cloudwatch metrics using AWSSDK.CloudWatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445704/how-to-retrieve-aws-cloudwatch-metrics-using-awssdk-cloudwatch/51457113#51457113)

Comment: Had the same issue, adding region_name fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your MetricDataQueries setup looks correct to me for Invocations metric assuming your EndpointName and VariantName are correct.

It is a good call out per Tartaglia's 2nd point "Check that you're calling the correct region. " The default region is us-west-2.

Have you verified your metrics shown up in CloudWatch console?
If you are keep failing on fetching the metrics, you could also try to create a support case with SageMaker, so that you could provide more details like endpointArn, etc. to them and they can check the metric publishing on their side.

Best,
Johna